# magento 1.9 have issue with URL Rewrite Management and backlink from the same domain

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, redirect-url

I have a jewellery store site "finestgold.ca/store", there are approx 800 products, but in the URL Rewrite section it is showing "41701 records found" do I need to worry about site SEO ? if that much redirect cause problem?

Moreover, on Google webmaster my site showing

Top 14 pages linked from: finestgold.ca

Total links : 334,992 Total linked pages : 152

Can someone suggest how to fix this?
[image]

[image]